# MPI_File is incompatible with parameter of the "File" with fscanf

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to parallelize my program with MPI.

```
   MPI_File fh;                                                     
       MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD,"input.txt",MPI_MODE_CREATE|MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);
       if(rank == 0){
               nwords = -1;
               do {
                       err = fscanf(fh, "%[^\n]\n", word[++nwords]);
               } while( err != EOF && nwords < maxwords);
               printf("Read in %d words\n", nwords);
       }
```

then I got this error.

```
 warning #167: argument of type "MPI_File" is incompatible with parameter of type "FILE *__restrict__"
                          err = fscanf(fh, "%[^\n]\n", word[++nwords]);
```

how can I read a file using MPI_File_open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MPI_File_open` works with `MPI_File`, and `fscanf()` works with `FILE *` and there is no interoperability.

You have to either
 - `MPI_File_open()` and `MPI_File_read()`
 - or stick to `fopen()` and `fscanf()`

MPI-IO true potential is unleashed when doing collective IO (e.g. `MPI_File_read_all()`) and there is no such thing as `MPI_File_scanf()` so unless you are willing to `MPI_File_read_all()` and `sscanf()`, you might want to stick with non MPI subroutines.